# Web scrapping timeout due to waiting for reviews to load

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I wanted to write a python script through which I can read all the reviews of a particular location/shop on google maps. I tried with several modification in the code, but all the time , timeout exception is coming. Below is the code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

def scrape_google_reviews(url):
    # Set up Chrome WebDriver
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Run in headless mode, i.e., without opening browser window
    chromedriver_path = 'C:/Users/Downloads/chromedriver-win64/chromedriver.exe'  # Specify path to chromedriver executable
    service = Service(chromedriver_path)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

    # Load the Google Maps URL
    driver.get(url)

    # Wait for the reviews to load
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "ODSEW-ShBeI-content")))
    except TimeoutException as e:
        print("Timeout occurred while waiting for reviews to load:", e)
        driver.quit()
        return None
    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred while waiting for reviews to load:", e)
        driver.quit()
        return None

    # Extract review elements
    review_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "ODSEW-ShBeI-content")

    # Extract review details
    reviews = []
    for review_element in review_elements:
        review_text = review_element.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ODSEW-ShBeI-title").text
        reviews.append(review_text)

    # Close the WebDriver
    driver.quit()

    return reviews

# Example usage
url = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/FASTECH+SOLUTIONS/@18.5165309,73.8457059,18.29z/data=!4m6!3m5!1s0x3bc2c160b5caf2dd:0x6d49235d88bd5d25!8m2!3d18.5161858!4d73.8459712!16s%2Fg%2F11t7drcv4g?entry=ttu"
reviews = scrape_google_reviews(url)
if reviews:
    for i, review in enumerate(reviews, 1):
        print(f"Review {i}: {review}")
else:
    print("Failed to scrape reviews.")
```

I am not sure what is going wrong, I followed several blogs including one from geeksforgeeks and seems they are outdated. My chrome version is 122.0.6261.113 and I have downloaded chromedriver.exe from here: https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/122.0.6261.128/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip

Comment: 1.- I dont find any string on website html "ODSEW-ShBeI-content". 2- Care with iframes. Can you confirm you see "ODSEW" on the html? it can be dynamic name

Comment: No I don't see any "ODSEW" string. I this the issue ? As I have been trying different google maps urls and code from different sites

Comment: How do you pretend find something that dont exists? Try to know what you doing and not copy paste random code

Comment: I am sorry for that. I changed this selector with another one on html file : "MyEned" and this worked. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code which get the review.

instead of using dynamically created class for fetching review - I used `MyEned` which seems static.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

def scrape_google_reviews(url):
    # Set up Chrome WebDriver
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Run in headless mode, i.e., without opening browser window
    chromedriver_path = 'C:/Users/Downloads/chromedriver-win64/chromedriver.exe'  # Specify path to chromedriver executable
    service = Service(chromedriver_path)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

    # Load the Google Maps URL
    driver.get(url)

    # Wait for the reviews to load
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "MyEned")))
    except TimeoutException as e:
        print("Timeout occurred while waiting for reviews to load:", e)
        driver.quit()
        return None
    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred while waiting for reviews to load:", e)
        driver.quit()
        return None

    # Extract review elements
    review_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "MyEned")
    print("review_elemtns", review_elements)
    # Extract review details
    reviews = []
    for review_element in review_elements:
        review_text = review_element.get_attribute("textContent")
        reviews.append(review_text)

    # Close the WebDriver
    driver.quit()

    return reviews

# Example usage
url = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/FASTECH+SOLUTIONS/@18.5165309,73.8457059,18.29z/data=!4m6!3m5!1s0x3bc2c160b5caf2dd:0x6d49235d88bd5d25!8m2!3d18.5161858!4d73.8459712!16s%2Fg%2F11t7drcv4g?entry=ttu"
reviews = scrape_google_reviews(url)
if reviews:
    for i, review in enumerate(reviews, 1):
        print(f"Review {i}: {review}")
else:
    print("Failed to scrape reviews.")
```

here is the screenshot of output.
[image]

Comment: Why did you post a screenshot of the output rather than simply posting the text? The screenshot makes it difficult to read.

Comment: hmm yeah make sense - next time, will make sure to post the text.